# Ubuntu 14.04 is not recognizing my Wacom cintiq 13HD anymore after latest update

Tags: 14.04, wacom

After the update today (announced as hardware update), my beloved wacom is not recognized anymore (well, the pen is somehow recognized, but in the settings section it says there is no wacom tablet connected). I am using a hp envy dv6 computer with Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8, a geforce gt 635m...reinstalled the wacom drivers via Synaptic but...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing the latest driver via Sourceforge?

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom

Comment: Well, did not try this as wacom was ewcognized out-of-the-box before..will do when I have time

Comment: Hey AaronI found your post on exactly my problem on another forum (as iI was trying to install the correspondnt xorg server, but I am not sure which version of ubuntu I am using...how do I find out?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but to answer your question "lsb_release -a" will tell you about your OS. You may need to install a package to get lsb_release. "uname -a" can also be helpful for your kernel version.